# Unable to route non existing paths in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mobile-angular-ui

I am unable to route the path `code/:code` in my website. I receive the following error:

> Firefox can't find the file at /C:/Code/dola/mobileweb/app/code/123

`default.htm` is located in the `app` folder.

I am using the `mobileangularui` framework. I have the following routes declared (among others):

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: 'codeview.htm', reloadOnSearch: false });
    $routeProvider.when('/code/:code', { templateUrl: 'codeview.htm', reloadOnSearch: false });
});
```

Everything works fine, except when I try e.g. `code/12345`.

This route is intended for a call from outside, e.g. `www.mywebsite.com/code/12345`.

Comment: Your templateUrl is relative to the path. it's looking for 'codeview.htm' in '/code/:code', because you provided a file name without a path.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues. First is re-declaring the $routeProvider unnecessarily. The second is you don't have an "otherwise" clause to catch everything you aren't already.
Also, not an error, but good practice to follow; you are missing a controller and controllerAs explicit directive for each entry. Try this:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
     templateUrl: 'codeview.htm'
     , controller: 'HomeController'
     , controllerAs: 'vm'
     , reloadOnSearch: false
  })
  .otherwise({
     redirectTo: '/'
  })
});
```

This was based on the assumption that '/code/:code' is not its own page. The option is easy to add/change if this is not the case, following the above model.

Hope this helps.

-C§

-edit-

It looks as though the best way to do this (as with what I've done in my current project for such needs) is to store the code into a global (model) variable and call the redirect using `$location.path('/');`. Something like the below would be part of the click-function:

```
DataService.code = vm.code; //the code value selected
$location.path('/');
```

And the resulting page would have as part of its initialization routine:

```
vm.code = DataService.code; //retrieves the code from memory
//and uses it to populate the page appropriately
```

I'm unfamiliar with how to specify a URL and have it read what page it should populate based on the trailer, aside from using PHP to catch the URL extension with the index and a [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) redirection process. I know this can be achieved using AJAX or a Jquery catch, but I'm still somewhat new to JavaScript as a whole and not sure what the process would look like.

Alternatively, you could designate a page for each possible code (ex: 12345.html || 12345.php).

Hope this also helps.

-C§